# Shell script tirar extensao e procurar só pelo nome

Tags: bash, shell, linux

Alguém pode corrigir o meu script?

O objetivo do script é comparar os ficheiros de entrada com os ficheiro na pasta **LIXO**, o problema é que se o ficheiro de entrada for `teste1.txt` ele não encontra o ficheiro `teste1.tar.bz2`

```
#!/bin/bash

##CONSTANTES##

dir="/home/pasta/LIXO"

#check para ver se é file#
if ! [ -e $1 ]; then
        echo "Not a file!"
        exit 0
fi

###main###
#ciclo for para aceitar multiplas entradas de ficheiros##
for file in "$@"; do
#se o ficheiro de entrada existir no diretorio /LIXO#
if [[ -f $dir/$file ]]; then
        echo "|||File EXISTS|||"
#se o file de entrada for mais novo do que o file que lá está#
        if [[ $file -nt $2 ]]; then
                echo "file is newer"
        fi
else
echo "File doesnt exist, ziping it and moving"
fi
done


#to:do
#add tar / mv /rm
#eventualmente adicionar os comandos para fazer Zip do ficheiro e mover.
```

Comment: `teste1.txt` é a mesma coisa que `teste1.tr.bz2`, assim o objetivo principal é comparar `"teste1" == "teste1"` correto? Ou ainda  precisa compactar o arquivo e mover ele?

Comment: neste momento sim! eventualmente irei adicionar os comandos para fazer Tar e mover o ficheiro, o problema é que ele n encontra o ficheiro zipado!

Answer (score 1):

Para remover o sufixo `.*` de uma variável basta referenciá-la como `${variavel%%.*}`. Assim você poderia corrigir o seu script e resolver o problema:

```bsh
#ciclo for para aceitar multiplas entradas de ficheiros##
for file in "$@"; do
    #se o ficheiro de entrada existir no diretorio /LIXO#
    fileprefix="${file%%.*}"
    if [[ -f "$dir/$fileprefix" ]]; then
        echo "|||File EXISTS|||"
        #se o file de entrada for mais novo do que o file que lá está#
        if [[ $file -nt $2 ]]; then
                echo "file is newer"
        fi
    else
        echo "File doesnt exist, ziping it and moving"
    fi
done
```